# Why is not the D'Alembert operator a scalar?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I am taking a course on classical electrodynamics and my professor has defined the D'Alembert operator to me as:

$$\square=\eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}$$

I have been operating using this definition because I know that what it means is (in a 4-dimensional Minkowski space):

$$\square = -\partial_0 \partial_0 + \partial_1 \partial_1 + \partial_2 \partial_2 + \partial_3 \partial_3$$

But today I was looking again at this definition and I started having some doubts. The D'Alembert operator is defined as a (2,0) tensor acting on two vectors. **Shouldn't it be then just a scalar?** Why is it not just a number?

I'm sure it is a fairly elemental question but I can't understand it right now.

Comment: Actually, d’Alembertian _is_ a  Lorentz scalar and not a (2,0)-tensor: $\square = \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} \equiv \sum_{\mu , \nu} \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}$. Therefore, no indices remain after the sum; it is a 0-rank tensor, not something like $A_{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: @PhilosophiæNaturalis Yes, that was what I meant (the metric acting on the two partial derivatives). But shouldn't it have a fixed value then for a given basis of the tangent space?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see what you mean! It has a fixed value for a given basis. You can actually prove that it is a scalar, simply by looking at its invariance under coordinate transformations.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding begins with the statement “d'Alembert operator is defined as a (2,0)-tensor acting on two vectors” which is not true -- you ignore the contraction in $\mu, \nu$ apparently! Furthermore, in general, scalars need not be simple numbers. A scalar is defined solely by its behaviour under coordinate transformations (should be invariant under such a transformation).

Comment: I see the problem now. The metric is not "acting" in the partial derivatives. In that case I would have to express the equation as $\partial_{\mu} \eta^{\mu}_{\nu} \partial^{\nu}$. I think I understand it now. Thanks.

Comment: Not yet perhaps. First note that $A_\mu B_\nu g^{\mu \nu}$ is manifestly a scalar for any $A$, $B$, and $g$. Should I refer you to a reference?

Comment: @PhilosophiæNaturalis I would appreciate it. I come from a mathematical background and I can't stop thinking of the metric as a bilinear symmetric form acting on two elements of the tangent space, maybe my misunderstanding comes from that point of view.

Comment: I would recommend Hassani, S. “Mathematical Physics” (1st ed., 1999), $\S$ 25.4. It would be an easy read for you with a mathematical background. Furthermore, you can ask the question in `math.stackexchange` if you prefer more mathematical rigour. [That might be the reason someone has made a down-vote on this question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say in the comments that you think of the metric as a bilinear symmetric form acting on two vectors. This is correct, of course. What we're doing here is pretending that the operator $\partial$ is a covector, and acting with the metric (the inverse metric, actually) on two copies of it: $\Box = \eta(\partial, \partial) = \eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu$. This is not perfectly rigorous since $\partial$ isn't an element of the cotangent space, but its components $\partial_\mu$ behave as if they were the components of a covector. This means that the resulting operator is a scalar: for any scalar function $f$, $\Box f$ is a scalar.

You might be confused because there are two meaning of "acting on" here. The metric acts on vectors (or covectors) because it is a tensor; if you give it two vectors you get a number. The D'Alembertian $\Box$ and the gradient $\partial$ are differential operators and they act on functions, returning another function in the case of $\Box$ or a covector in the case of $\partial$.

Comment: An answer clear enough!